How to add Suffix in openapi generator in spring boot gradle?
I am using openapi generator to generate the interface and models from openapi specification. Everything is working fine. But, I want to have suffix in my model name. For example: Employee would be EmployeeDTO. I have added "modelSuffix" in configOptions in openApiGenerate config in my grade as follows.
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.6'
    id 'org.sonarqube' version '5.1.0.4882'
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'com.adarshr.test-logger' version '4.0.0'
    id 'com.diffplug.spotless' version '7.0.0.BETA1'
    id 'org.openapi.generator' version '7.7.0'
}

openApiGenerate {
    generatorName = 'spring'
    inputSpec = file('src/main/resources/api-spec/api.yaml').absolutePath
    outputDir = file('build/generated').absolutePath
    apiPackage = 'com.abhi.api'
    modelPackage = 'com.abhi.model'
    invokerPackage = 'com.abhi.invoker'
    configOptions = [
            interfaceOnly: 'true',
            useOptional: 'false',
            dateLibrary: 'java8',
            implementationPackage: '', // Prevent generation of implementation classes
            skipDefaultInterface: 'true', // Skip generation of default methods
            modelSuffix: 'DTO',
            useTags: 'true',
    ]
}

But it doesn't have effect. Could you please give me any solution?

I just deleted "modelSuffix" from configOptions  and then added modelNameSuffix = 'DTO' under openApiGenerate. And now it works. Following is the complete code.
openApiGenerate {
    generatorName = 'spring'
    inputSpec = file('src/main/resources/api-spec/api.yaml').absolutePath
    outputDir = file('build/generated').absolutePath
    apiPackage = 'com.abhi.api'
    modelPackage = 'com.abhi.model'
    invokerPackage = 'com.abhi.invoker'
    modelNameSuffix = 'DTO' // move it to here
    configOptions = [
            interfaceOnly: 'true',
            useOptional: 'false',
            dateLibrary: 'java8',
            implementationPackage: '', // Prevent generation of implementation classes
            skipDefaultInterface: 'true', // Skip generation of default methods
            useTags: 'true'
    ]
}

